# How can we compare two JSON files when element keys are different but values are same

Tags: comparison, rest-assured

I have two JSON response strings from two API's

API1 Response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "sets": [
        {
          "type": "adImg",
          "imgs": {
            "attributes": [
              {
                "name": "bottomPadding",
                "value": "true"
              }
            ],
            "img": {
              "links": [
                {
                  "linkType": "PRODUCT",
                  "label": "123",
                  "value": "1526783"
                }
              ]}}}]}]}
```

API2 Response:

```
{
  “values”: [
    {
      “contents”: [
        {
          "attributes": [
              {
                "attrName": "bottomPadding",
                "attrValue": "true"
              }
            ],
            "nested-Content": {
              "content": [
                {
                  “type”: "PRODUCT",
                  “id”: "123",
                  “val”: "1526783"
                }
              ]}}}]}]}
```

**Key names in API1 response are**: name, value, linkType, label, value

**Key names in API2 response are**: attrName, attrValue, type, id, val

But the element values are the same in both API responses.

How can we compare the two API responses to confirm the values are the same?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, I think extract-then-compare part by part is shortest way (in term of coding line).

```java
List<Object> first = new ArrayList<>(JsonPath.from(json1).getMap("data[0].sets[0].imgs.attributes[0]").values());
List<Object> first2 = new ArrayList<>(JsonPath.from(json2).getMap("values[0].contents[0].attributes[0]").values());
assertThat(first).isEqualTo(first2);

List<Object> second = new ArrayList<>(JsonPath.from(json1).getMap("data[0].sets[0].imgs.img.links[0]").values());
List<Object> second2 = new ArrayList<>(JsonPath.from(json2).getMap("values[0].contents[0]['nested-Content'].content[0]").values());
assertThat(second).isEqualTo(second2);
```

If you want to solve that in a general way, option would be mapping API response to Java object, then compare 2 objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response!!, yeah, I am looking for Object comparison only. Could you please give me the solution to create objects for both responses and compare them?

Comment: This article may help you https://phauer.com/2016/testing-restful-services-java-best-practices/#use-pojos-and-object-mapping I don't want to write POJOs solution for this complex response. It's unnecessary.